# Ews( Exchange Web Services- mIcrosoft) Java Api, creating ExchangeService Bean in Spring

Tags: spring, exchangewebservices

I am using EWS Java Api in Spring rest, I have using specific one user credential for the whole app, Actually i just need to get the mail from Inbox for this user only.

So here because i have a specific user so instead of creating instance of ExchangeService(new ExchangeService()) every time i just created a ExchangeService bean.

```
 @Bean
    public ExchangeService exchangeService() throws Exception {
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
        ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("email", "password");
        service.setCredentials(credentials);
        service.autodiscoverUrl(username, new RedirectionUrlCallback());
        return service;
    }
```

So I have some questions here:

- Does this is a good idea to creating a bean of exchangeService because here i am not sure about expired time limit for ExchangeService?
- Is there any specific expired time limit for exchangeService?